Load balanced QGIS servers - shared file system
I would like to setup 2 virtual machines running QGIS Server in a load balanced environment.
The load balancer will:

handle SSL termination, and redirect HTTP to HTTPS.

The two servers will:

run Ubuntu Linux
run QGIS Server
run Apache as a reverse proxy

I intend the two servers to both mount a common filesystem (ext3) that has the QGS project files and the data. Will I run into trouble with the shared file system?

I don't know how that would be possible, but if it is, Its not GIS-specific. The only shared (single point of failure) filesystem would be an an NFS file share.

I think questions about how QGIS Server runs is a GIS question. The reason is because I believe the only source of problem would be if the QGIS on one server locks the project file. In this instance, it would not be able to serve the project file on two servers at once.
